# keeping google indexes while rebuilding a website in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website which is developed in asp.net.And all the site having over 60000 google indexes.

Now i want to rebuild it in asp.net mvc. The domain name still remain ..But the link to seperate pages will change.. Is it cause to lose google indexs of that page.

for example ..www.domain.com/product/help.aspx  .. it is the current link ..

but i guess after rebuilding it will change like

www.domain.com/product/help

I want to persist all the google indexs already have in my site. How can i do that easily.. I am expecting suggestions and ideas .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 301 (Moved permanently) redirect

This will tell search engines that your url's have moved permanently and allow them to update their index.

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633&&hl=en

A list of ways to do this in your server side language of choice.

http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

In MVC3 you need [RedirectToActionPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453902%28v=VS.98%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently going through the same process and am using the [URL Rewriting module for IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) to map all my existing pages to their new locations.

[This article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) uses an example which is very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

To allow google to understand that you have changed the pages you will need to use a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect, and the URL Rewriting module will allow you to use this response with all the redirects you make.

It is also worth looking at the [rewrite maps](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/) article, as this can be very useful when you have large sets of rewrite rules.